# Rename Files in a Directory

Tags: python

I have 400 files in a directory (with `.png` extensions). They start with the name `005.png` and go up to `395.png`.

I want to rename them using `os.rename`:

```
os.rename(006.png,005.png)
```

In other words, I want to shift all the numbers down one, renaming the file `005.png` to `004.png` and renaming `395.png` to `394.png`, and so on.

I don't want to do this manually, because it would take too long:

```
os.rename(005.png,004.png)
os.rename(006.png,005.png)
...
```

How can I do this simply? I am using the s60 2nd edition FP3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Please give me a code" — we don't do that here. Show us what you've tried and where you've run into problems, and we will try to help. We won't write your code for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple loop:

```
for i in xrange(4, 396):
    os.rename(str(i).zfill(3) + ".png", str(i-1).zfill(3) + ".png"))
```

and that's about it :)

Answer (score 2):

A loop is the easiest indeed. As an alternative to `str(i).zfill(3) + ".png"`, you could use

```
template = "{0:03d}.png"
for i in range(4, 396):
    os.rename(template.format(i), template.format(i-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
path  = r"C:\your_dir"#i've added r for skipping slash , case you are in windows
os.chdir(path)#well here were the problem , before edit you were in different directory and you want  edit file which is in another directory , so you have to change your directory to the same path you wanted to change some of it's file 
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    name,ext = file.split('.')
    edited_name=str(int(name)-1)
    os.rename(file,edited_name+'.'+ext)
```

hopefully that's what are you looking up for

Comment: I try your code and python say's
"os.rename(file,newName)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
>>>"

Comment: Sir .. it says
>>> ===== RESTART =====
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ped.py", line 1061, in run_click
  File "D:\Ped.temp\Unnamed1.py", line 7, in ?
    os.rename("file","newName")
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>> 
why ?
I put the exact file path on it !

Comment: i've make the final edit , and i'm sure 100% it's going to work :)

Comment: Sir .. Thankyou for your reply ! Your code works .. But my 3 digit file name becames 2 ..
File:
005.png became 05.png ..
i want it to be:
005.png become 004.png and so on ..

005.png to 004.png
006.png to 005.png and so on .. up to
395.png became 394.png !

Thankyou very much ..